# Central Logging Options - need flat file as well as elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, elasticsearch, centralized-logging

I would like to have ephemeral ec2 instances push logs to a central flat-file store for archiving and manual perusing, as well has have that data pushed to elastic search.

Is there a single agent that can tail local log files and both push them to a central flat-file store as well as push them to elastic search?

Comment: What kind of logs are we talking? Plain syslog?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for.. Logstash!!!

But seriously though, install [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) on your central logging server, and push the logs there with [Logstash-Forwarder](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder), using the Lumberjack protocol.

In Logstash, you can setup multiple outputs, which can be Elastic and local flat files with whatever format you want.